# Parallel Ajax calls not setting Variable value first time they are called

Tags: jquery

I am testing Parallel Jquery Ajax calls with

```
   // $.When{}.done(fucntion(){// Something Here});
```

The Problem is whenthis page gets loaded and i press the button to invoke delegate() method, it does print Test1, Test2 and Test3 Not the Text which is being set through ajax calls. Can anyone spot an issue?

```
var response = [];
 response.method1 = 'Test1';
response.method2 = 'Test2';
response.method3 = 'Test3';
function method1() {
     $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/Home/Method1',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            response.method1 = data.Name;
        },
        error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $("#error").html(jqXhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}

function method2() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/Home/Method2',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            response.method2 = data.Name;
        },
        error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $("#error").html(jqXhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}

function method3() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/Home/Method3',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            response.method3 = data.Name;
        },
        error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $("#error").html(jqXhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}

function deletegate() {
    $.when(Progress(true),method1(), method2(), method3()).done(function () {
        $("#response").append(response.method1 + '<br/>' + response.method2 + '<br/>' + response.method3 );
        Progress(false);

    } );
}

function Progress(show) {

    if (show) {
        $("#Prog").show();
    } else {
        $("#Prog").hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because all your JS-functions return immediately without a return value, so .done is also called immediately and not waiting for async-call to end.
guess: try return $.ajax(...) inside these functions

Comment: Great, well spotted. Added return and it worked fine.